# Weird behavior when trying to edit a constant variable through a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, constants

In order to improve my knowledge regarding pointers and constants, I wrote the following code:

```
int main() {
    const int value = 2;
    int *pvalue = &value;
    *pvalue = 3;

    printf("value: %d\n", value);
    printf("*pvalue: %d\n", *pvalue);
    printf("&value: %p\n", &value);
    printf("pvalue: %p", pvalue);
    return 0;
}
```

From what I understand, `value` cannot be edited directly because it is declared as a `const`. Nonetheless, it can be edited indirectly through `*pvalue`. At least, it's how I understand the warning below thrown by the compiler on line `int *pvalue = &value;`.

**warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]|**

However, when I run the code, here's the output I get:

```
value: 2
*pvalue: 3
&value: 000000000060FE1C
pvalue: 000000000060FE1C
```

`value` and `*pvalue` are different, but it seems like they are pointing to the same memory address.

What am I missing?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: @stark Are you saying `*pvalue` is actually uninitialized?

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nasal%20demons

Comment: @stark I understand now. "Undefined behavior" is a new concept to me. This page helped me clarify it: https://devtut.github.io/c/undefined-behavior.html#dereferencing-a-pointer-to-variable-beyond-its-lifetime

Comment: The title is incorrect. Whatever behavior occurs when trying to edit a constant object is not weird. Trying to edit a constant object is weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring the compiler diagnosis, which you should not.

Anyway, with `const` you prohibit write access to the qualified object. And the compiler will not accept `value = 23;`, for sure.

But by the pointer you removed this limitation, and invoked Undefined Behavior. On the actual target, since the variable is most probably located on the stack, it is writable by hardware means. Such a behavior is included in "undefined".

Put it into static memory, and most probably you will get a runtime exception, because the variable will be allocated in write-protected memory.

Comment: Your comment as well as stark's made me learn about undefined behavior, which was the missing piece in the puzzle for me. This page helped me further: https://devtut.github.io/c/undefined-behavior.html

Comment: Well, they _commented_, I _answered_. ;-)